# If AWS Sessions Manager executes a file in EC2, which user in the executed EC2 executes the file?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, runcommand

When I execute a sh file in EC2 using AWS Sessions Manager's Run Command, does the user (root or other user I created) configured in the executed EC2 execute the sh? Also, how do I know which user executed it?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what user it is?

Answer (score 1):

It runs as **root**. You can simply check it by running the following command in Run Command:

```
whoami > /tmp/info
```

Then login to the instance and check `/tmp/info`. You can do same for working directory `pwd >> /tmp/info` or any parameter you want to check.